# AngularJS : send user activity to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to send user activity to server, especially which button user clicked.

I know I can do this like this.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="pressA()">A</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="pressB()">B</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.pressA = function() {
  sendServer("A");
  // Do other things for button A
}

$scope.pressB = function() {
  sendServer("B");
  // Do other things for button B
}

function sendServer(msg) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var params = "msg=" + encodeURIComponent(msg);
  req.open("POST", "/scripts/log");
  req.send(params);
}
```

But this way require me to insert `sendServer` to all ng-click event. It is bothersome. Can I do this more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute something for each `ng-click` you define, you can define a custom `ngClick` directive to do the job.

```
.directive('ngClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1, // built-in ngClick has priority 0
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        // do something
      });
    }
  }
});
```

However, this will not cover every actions (aHref, ngSubmit...).

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the `sendServer()` function in the scope and pass the arguments with the `ng-click` directive?

Example:

```
$scope.sendServer = function(message) {
  // do things
}
```

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="pressA('A')">A</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="pressB('B')">B</button>
```

Comment: I updated my post. What `pressA` and `pressB` does is not only sending log . Each button has individual behavior.