# AngularJS : send the checkbox / radio button value to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to send user activity to server. In my [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767704/angularjs-send-user-activity-to-server), I asked `ng-click` case. This question is about checkbox and radio button case.

I would like to send to server which checkbox or radio button user clicked for logging user activity.

I know I can do it like this.

HTML:

```
<!-- for checkbox -->
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left" uib-btn-checkbox>Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" uib-btn-checkbox>Right</label>
</div>

<!-- for radio button-->
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Left'">Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Right'">Right</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.$watch('checkModel', function() {
    sendServer("checkModel" + JSON.stringify(checkModel));
    // Do other things for checkModel
}, true);

$scope.$watch('radioModel', function() {
    sendServer("radioModel" + radioModel);
    // Do other things for radioModel
});

function sendServer(msg) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "msg=" + encodeURIComponent(msg);
    req.open("POST", "/scripts/log");
    req.send(params);
}
```

This way requires me to insert `sendServer` to all `watch`. This is inefficient. I would like to do it in an integrated way. Can I do it?

Comment: you can use `directive` for this

Comment: You can refer to here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767704/angularjs-send-user-activity-to-server?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Instead of doing raw `XMLHttpRequest`, use the [AngularJS $http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). The `$http` service is a core AngularJS service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest).

Comment: Also instead of doing `$watch`, use the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to run a function and inject the model value there, then you can do whatever you want

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left" ng-change="run(checkModel)" uib-btn-checkbox>Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle" ng-change="run(checkModel)" uib-btn-checkbox>Middle</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" ng-change="run(checkModel)" uib-btn-checkbox>Right</label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.run = function(item) {
    console.log(item); // will print the model object
    // run your sendServer function here
}
```

1. If you call the same function from both the checkbox group or from radio button group, you will get a different `item` resolved into the function, you can then use validation (type check) and get your relevant data.
2. You don't need to write any `$watch` this way because an `ng-change` directive already wraps one up for you. You will need to have an `ng-model`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-click` directly, this way instead of using the digest loop, you execute only on the event of click