# Angular : send user activity to server

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to send user activities to server, especially which button the user clicked.

What I would like to do is same with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767704/angularjs-send-user-activity-to-server) as I asked before. The post is AngularJS, what I would like to ask is Angular ( I am using Angular8 ).

I know I can do it like this.

HTML:

```
<button (click)="pressA()">A</buttion>
<button (click)="pressB()">B</buttion>
```

Typescript:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl:"my.html"
})
export class MyApp {

  pressA() {
    sendServer("A");
    // Do other things for button A
  }

  pressB() {
    sendServer("B");
    // Do other things for button B
  }


  sendServer(val: string) {
    // POST val to https://(mydomain)/(path)
  }  
}
```

But this way require me to insert sendServer to all click event. It is bothersome. Can I do this more efficient way?

Comment: You can still override the click directive in angular, but you might be better off just adding your own custom directive that does the same thing and adding it where needed

Comment: Use a directive with selector `button` and listen for click events on all buttons in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Reactgular comment, I have created a directive with `button` selector and `click` hostlistner.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'button',
})
export class OnClickDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event: MouseEvent) {

    const location = $event.view.location ;
    const pathName = decodeURI(location.pathname);
    const innterHtml: string = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;

    // send pathName and innterHtml to server.
    //    :

  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your use-case, I'd recommend that you use a directive and for every button that you write in your templates. The code would be somewhat like this

```html
<p>
  <button clickMonitor>1</button>
  <button clickMonitor>2</button>
  <button clickMonitor (clickEmitter) = "data($event)">3</button>
</p>
```

Here's this Angular demo how to achieve this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5rjtp

Now, there's multiple scope of enhancements here, like you can add a debounce effect on the clicks, so that you don't end up calling the server multiple times. 
This directive you might not wanna add on some buttons that you don't wish to track.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the argument to the function, that way you reutilize code:

HTML:

```
<button (click)="press('A')"></button>
<button (click)="press('B')"></button>
```

Typescript:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl:"my.html"
})
export class MyApp {

  press(arg: string) {
    sendServer(arg);
  }

}
```

Don't know if that's what you are looking for. Also I recommend creating a service for your server calls.